# How to fix an issue of VS code terminal prompt adding an extra line to it after the program is executed

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-python

[image]My VS Code is appending the miniconda3 path to the Power Shell prompt
every time I execute any code. This causes the PS prompt to be super long.

e.g.

`PS C:\Users\name\Projects\Python Tutorials> **& C:/Users/name/miniconda3/python.exe "c:/Users/name/Projects/Python Tutorials/Instance_in_Python.py**"`

I would like the command prompt to end at:

`PS C:\Users\name\Projects\Python Tutorials>`

and print the program's output and not append this extra line after it:

`**& C:/Users/name/miniconda3/python.exe "c:/Users/name/Projects/Python Tutorials/Instance_in_Python.py**`

I have attached a screenshot of the PS prompt in VS Terminal for your perusal.

I have also searched this forum for any possible solution for this issue but unfortunately could not find any.

Is this due to the location of my Python file and the project files or something else? Any help in reducing this command prompt line would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Is this also happening in your regular terminal? Try and run your program through your regular Terminal to see if it's an issue with VSCode or not

Comment: The code executes in the Windows cmd terminal without having any issues mentioned above. This issue happens only while running the code in the VS code power shell terminal.

Comment: So, can you use the Command Prompt or Git Bash or some other terminal option in VS Code to avoid this?  Do you have a particular need for the PowerShell Terminal in VS Code?  That line appears to be the command invoking the Python interpreter in your conda environment to execute your script, which is pretty standard for any VS Code Terminal, but I don't immediately recognize the `**&` part of the syntax (I admittedly don't use PowerShell much)

Comment: I can certainly do that. But as I keep working most of the time on VS Code, would prefer the Power Shell Terminal of the VS code.  This append happens only when the vs code prints the output but otherwise when it is waiting for command input, it shows the normal PS prmpt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My VS Code is appending the miniconda3 path to the Power Shell prompt every time I execute any code. This causes the PS prompt to be super long.

vscode uses the system terminal as the integrated terminal, that's how it works. There's nothing wrong with that.

If you insist on cleaner output, you can use [Code Runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner) and keep the following settings.

```
    "code-runner.runInTerminal": false,
    "code-runner.clearPreviousOutput": true,
    "code-runner.showExecutionMessage": false,
```

[image]

*But I still recommend you to use the official extension Python (`Run Python File`) to execute the script.*

Comment: I have copied and pasted your JSon settings to my user preferences file. However, for me to get a clear output from the output tab, I still have to first run the command in the terminal tab and then change to "Run Code" and re-run the program to get the output under the Output tab. Is there any other setting/s I need to change to run the command and get the output from the output tab in the very first attempt?

Comment: I can't clearly understand what you are saying? Just right-click and select `Run Code` and Code Runner will be used to execute the script. No additional settings are required. Or click the triangle button in the upper right corner to select `Run Code`, or use the shortcut key `Ctrl+Alt+N`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your valuable advice. I have realized that I wasn't able to get the output directly under the OUTPUT tab of the terminal because I was executing the code without first saving my working code file and then executing it. Earlier I used to execute the code as I kept writing it and run the Python file "Triangle Symbol"  and would get the output from the 'TERMINAL' tab without saving the work first.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you would be happier with this, but a VScode extension **code-runner** looks well-known.

[image]

Installing this extension enables you to see **[Run Code]** option with your python script, and at least it makes you save lines from including whole absolute path for your python.exe.

[image]

Comment: I am currently using the Code Runner extension. However, the only issue here I get is that when I run the code for the first time, it would produce its output only in the Power Shell terminal. But if rerun the same code, I would be able to see clear results in the output window. BTW, do you know if any way I can make the VS Code produce the result in the output window in the first run of the code?